# Is $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} \iff x = y$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the following statement true for $x \geq 0,y \geq 0$?
$$
\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} \iff x = y
$$
Starting with the statement on the left, multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{x}$:
$$
\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} \cdot \sqrt{x}
$$
Since it is assumed that $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y}$, then:
$$
\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} \cdot \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} \cdot \sqrt{y} \\
\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{y^2}
$$
Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: The converse is not quite true, because for example $-1=-1$, but you cannot take the square root. You must assume that $x$ and $y$ are both nonnegative to go from the right side to the left. For the other direction, just multiply the equality by itself!

Comment: I don't think it's _necessarily_ true. What's the domain of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @AndrewChin It is true for any reasonable restriction of $\sqrt{}$ to a function.

Comment: Just edited my post to include domains.

Comment: You shouldn’t go from $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}$ to $\sqrt{x^2}$. You should go from $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}$ to $x$ itself. After all, $\sqrt{x}$ is, **by definition** the unique nonnegative number whose square is equal to $x$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the help! Would you like to make this an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

If $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$, then it makes sense to take square roots.

Consequently, we deduce that
\begin{align*}
x = y & \Longleftrightarrow x - y = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt{x})^{2} - (\sqrt{y})^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}) = 0\\\\
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Your last step unnecessarily complicates things. Just go straight to $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x} =x$ and $\sqrt{y} \sqrt{y} =y$ by definition.

The other direction is basically tautologically true. If $x=y$ then their image under $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ must not be ambiguous, hence $\sqrt{x} =\sqrt{y}$

(Note that here f can without problems be defined such that $f: \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), x\mapsto \{-\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x}\}$, not neglecting the fact that the square root technically produces 2 outputs)

Answer (score 1):

If $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y}$, then you can square both sides to obtain x =y. But the other way is tricky, if x =y and you are taking square root on both sides, you have option to take either positive or negative square root. If you take both of them to be positive, then they are equal or if you take both of them to be negative, they are equal. For example, if x=4, y= 4; when you take square root if the sign of both square roots are same, only then they will be equal.